# How to send app specific payload in AWS SNS using Java SDK?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, apple-push-notifications, amazon-sns

Based on [Creating the Remote Notification Payload](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html)
 it is possible to send App specific data to SNS for example `acme2` in

```
{
    "aps" : { "alert" : "Message received from Bob" },
    "acme2" : [ "bang",  "whiz" ]
}
```

How do set that data in Java using [AmazonSNS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sns/AmazonSNS.html)

```
final PublishRequest publishRequest = new PublishRequest();
publishRequest
    .withTargetArn(getDeviceEndpoint())
    .withMessage(notification.getMessage())
    .withSubject(notification.getTitle());

return snsClient.publish(publishRequest).getMessageId();
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out i need to set message type to json

```
 publishRequest
                .withTargetArn(userByUsername.get().getDeviceEndpoint())
                .withMessage("{... json here ... }")
                .withSubject(enclosedNotificiation.getTitle())
                .withMessageStructure("json")
```

Comment: When you set the structure don't forget to add default filed in JSON payload otherwise, It causes error.